# Attributes generating no output using PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer and I wonder why the Point outpot port let's me use all attributes, whereas the Area output port generates no output for some attributes that I need to use.

What is the solution here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow arrows indicate that the connected Writer is (manually) set to not output the respective attributes. In order to turn all arrows to "green" the Writer has to be modified here (manually add the fields under "User Attributes" in the writer's settings or change attribute list to "automatic").

Comment: I answered my own question because I [got the helpful hint to solve it in the FME forum](https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q00009kQCfhSAG/pointonareaoverlayer-transformer-in-fme-why-do-some-attributes-generate-no-output-yellow-arrows?t=1661774365581).